# Can't change select option item angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel

I have a select option like this:

```
<select ng-init="filterSelected = getItems.data.key" 
        ng-model="filterSelected" 
        ng-options="data.key as data.label for data in getItems.data" ></select>
```

In which i parse a json that returns me some results that shows as item in this select. This is not a problem, i can display the items but i can't change them. It it stuck on the first one and even if i try to change the value still shows the first. By the way, i have a function in my javascript:

```
$scope.getObjects = function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.getItems.data.length; i++) {
                if($scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[i].key){
                    return $scope.getItems.data[i].objects;
                }
            }
        };
```

this function needs because i have to find the correct object to cycle in my json that is something like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "label": "first",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            ----,
                            ----,
                            ----
                        },
                        {
                            ----,
                            ----,
                            ----
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "1"
        },
        ---
        ---
```

so i can find the "object" i selected and i can find the correct attributes of that object. The problem is that is stuck. the results are correct but it shows only the first.. Maybe there is a problem with the model?

Comment: `filterSelected = getItems.data.key` here `getItems.data.key` is _undefined_ because `getItems.data` is array and does not have _key_ property

Comment: So how could i solve? what do you suggest?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: I think not. because the page is really big and each part of code is is related to another... if you can show me something to help me with the info i wrote you help me a lot

Comment: in fiddle you need just this select with sample data, not need full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76417/discussion-between-grundy-and-end-game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select what value you want select in [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

in your code you select *key* field, and then by key try get *objects*, but you can get *objects* at once

```
<select
    ng-model="filterSelected" 
    ng-options="data.objects as data.label for data in getItems.data" ></select>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getItems = {
      "data": [{
        "label": "first",
        "objects": [{
          "name": "firstObj",
          "attributes": [{
            "att1": "asd",
            "att2": "asd2"
          }, {
            "att3": "asd3",
            "att4": "asd4"
          }]
        }],
        "key": "1"
      }, {
        "label": "second",
        "objects": [{
          "name": "secondObj",
          "attributes": [{
            "att1": "asd",
            "att2": "asd2"
          }, {
            "att3": "asd3",
            "att4": "asd4"
          }]
        }],
        "key": "2"
      }]

    };
    $scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[0].objects;
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mycontroller'>
  <select ng-model="filterSelected" ng-options="data.objects as data.label for data in getItems.data"></select>

  {{filterSelected}}
</div>
```

**UPDATE** for comment, so you need save full object, instead just object, label or key properties.

```
<select
    ng-model="filterSelected" 
    ng-options="data.label for data in getItems.data" ></select>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getItems = {
      "data": [{
        "label": "first",
        "objects": [{
          "name": "firstObj",
          "attributes": [{
            "att1": "asd",
            "att2": "asd2"
          }, {
            "att3": "asd3",
            "att4": "asd4"
          }]
        }],
        "key": "1"
      }, {
        "label": "second",
        "objects": [{
          "name": "secondObj",
          "attributes": [{
            "att1": "asd",
            "att2": "asd2"
          }, {
            "att3": "asd3",
            "att4": "asd4"
          }]
        }],
        "key": "2"
      }]

    };
    $scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[0];
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mycontroller'>
  <select ng-model="filterSelected" ng-options="data.label for data in getItems.data"></select>

  <div>objects: {{filterSelected.objects}}</div>
  <div>key: {{filterSelected.key}}</div>

</div>
```

Comment: i'm sorry but is it possible show, always using this jsfiddle.net/k6s357L8/2 also the "key" selected? i mean for example show just on bottom of the select a <h1> tag with inside for example <h1>first</h1>

Comment: see here: https://jsfiddle.net/k6s357L8/3/ but in this way i don't know which this the index..now is static as 2!

Comment: Hi Grundy, i have only one more question for you and i hope you can help me. If you want, here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046867/group-same-json-attribute-in-an-array thanks really